# Creating two dimensional list and then making a DataFrame in Scala

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, maven

I have a date format list: (day,hour,minute) --> (5,3,12)
I want to insert to these data into the list. e.g. ((5,3,12),(1,14,21),...)
I am new at Scala and I do not know how to do this. And then I need to create a DataFrame from these data.

```
data = Seq(
      (l , m , r)
      ).toDF("day", "hour", "minutes")
```

Like this. If anyone can show me to best practice of doing this I would be appreciate. Thanks! Maybe I need to open my question more. I have done the same thing in Python. İt seems like:

```
for index in table:
  index = str(index)
  parts = index.split(" ") #first element is part0
  hours_minutes_second = parts[1].split(":")
  year = parts[0].split("-")
  dates=(year[0],year[1],year[2],hours_minutes_second[0],hours_minutes_second[1],hours_minutes_second[2])
  data.append(dates)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['day','hours','minutes'])
```

You don not have to worry about index and formats of data. What I need is that creating like two dimensional list and then making dataframe of it!

[
( '25', '06', '55'),
( '24', '14', '51'),
( '24', '06', '24'),
( '24', '03', '42'),
( '23', '19', '30')]

Comment: Are you using Spark dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, I assume that you want to create a Spark Dataframe that
is quite different to a Scala List.

To create a DataFrame you need to create the Schema first. You can do it like:

```
val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("day", IntegerType),
    StructField("hour", IntegerType),
    StructField("minutes", IntegerType)
  ))
```

There are several ways to create a DataFrame, for example:

Given a Seq[Row] you can create a RDD[Row] and then create the DataFrame from it:

```
val rdd : RDD[Row]= spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(5,3,12)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()

/*
+---+----+-------+
|day|hour|minutes|
+---+----+-------+
|  5|   3|     12|
+---+----+-------+
*/
```

For the case of a two dimensions list:

```
val schema2 = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("day", StringType),
    StructField("hour", StringType),
    StructField("minutes", StringType)
  ))

val list = List(
  Seq("25", "06", "55"),
  Seq("24", "14", "51"),
  Seq("24", "06", "24"),
  Seq("24", "03", "42"),
  Seq("23", "19", "30"))

val rdd : RDD[Row]= spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list.map(el => Row.fromSeq(el)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema2)

df.show()
/*
+---+----+-------+
|day|hour|minutes|
+---+----+-------+
| 25|  06|     55|
| 24|  14|     51|
| 24|  06|     24|
| 24|  03|     42|
| 23|  19|     30|
+---+----+-------+
*/
```